# sql statement complex condition "join"

Tags: mysql, sql

i have these 3 tables

```
1. course 
------------------------ 
CourseID     CourseName             
  1            English 1
  2            English 2
  3            Math 1
  4            Math 2
2. courseRequirements
------------------------
CourseID  ReqID                
   2        1
   4        3
3. studentcoursecomplete
-----------------------
CourseID   StudentID    
   1           5
```

i need a select statement do the following

1. show  course name from table course
2. don't show the course that student complete "studentcoursecomplete"
3. don't show the course that have a requirement that student didn't finish
4. show the course that have requirement that student finish

here in this example the result will be

```
CourseID      CourseName             
  2            English 2
  3            Math 1
```

because the student finish english 1 so he can't see it
and he didn't finish math 1 .. so he can't see math 2

my select statement do (1,2)
how can i do (3,4)
3-don't show the course that have a requirement that student didn't finish
4- show the course that have requirement that student finish

```
SELECT course.*
FROM course
LEFT JOIN studentcoursecomplete ON studentcoursecomplete.CourseID = course.CourseID
LEFT JOIN courseRequirements ON courseRequirements.CourseID = course.CourseID
WHERE studentcoursecomplete.CourseID IS NULL
```

Comment: *sniff sniff* oh yea, I love the smell of homework in the morning!

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is by getting the ones the user is not in and the ones that the user cant take and filter those out of the total result set.. something like this

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM course c
LEFT JOIN studentcoursecomplete scc ON scc.CourseID = c.CourseID
WHERE scc.studentid = 1 
  AND scc.CourseID IS NULL
  AND c.courseid NOT IN
(   SELECT cr.courseid 
    FROM courseRequirements cr
    WHERE cr.reqid IN
    (   SELECT c.courseid 
        FROM course c
        LEFT JOIN studentcoursecomplete scc ON scc.CourseID = c.CourseID 
        LEFT JOIN courseRequirements cr ON cr.CourseID = c.CourseID 
        WHERE scc.CourseID IS NULL
          AND EXISTS
          (   SELECT 1 FROM courserequirements cr1
              WHERE cr1.CourseID <> c.CourseID
              AND cr1.reqid = c.courseid
          )
     )
)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7c9a/1)

adjusting the OP's answer to include a specific user id...

```
SELECT c.*, sc.* 
FROM semestercourses AS sc 
NATURAL LEFT JOIN course AS c 
NATURAL LEFT JOIN courserequirements AS cr
NATURAL LEFT JOIN studentcoursecomplete AS scc
WHERE sc.CourseID NOT IN 
(   SELECT CourseID 
    FROM studentcoursecomplete WHERE sid = 1
)
    AND (cr.RequirementID IS NULL OR cr.RequirementID IN 
    (   SELECT CourseID 
        FROM studentcoursecomplete WHERE sid = 1
    )
)
```

Comment: thank's @JohnRuddell your answer give me the solution .. and that's work fine   ---------------------------------------                                 

SELECT c.*, sc.* FROM semestercourses AS sc
    NATURAL LEFT JOIN course AS c 
    NATURAL LEFT JOIN courserequirements AS cr
    NATURAL LEFT JOIN studentcoursecomplete AS scc
WHERE 
    sc.CourseID NOT IN (SELECT CourseID FROM studentcoursecomplete)
        AND 
    (cr.RequirementID IS NULL OR cr.RequirementID IN (SELECT CourseID FROM studentcoursecomplete))
----------
but this solution is for all users how can i make it for StudentID=1 ??

Comment: @GabrielBlanco i just edited to include a filter for a student :) try it and let me know if that works for you! :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell .. no that's not work .. the query give me all courses .. my query is work fine but i don't know where to put StudentID=1

Comment: @GabrielBlanco oh sorry put it in the wrong place.. try that

Comment: @JohnRuddell  nooo data ^_^ .. pro   pleease just help me in my query --------->
SELECT c.*, sc.* FROM semestercourses AS sc NATURAL LEFT JOIN course AS c NATURAL LEFT JOIN courserequirements AS cr NATURAL LEFT JOIN studentcoursecomplete AS scc WHERE sc.CourseID NOT IN (SELECT CourseID FROM studentcoursecomplete) AND (cr.RequirementID IS NULL OR cr.RequirementID IN (SELECT CourseID FROM studentcoursecomplete))
---------------------------------------
where to put SID=1 ?

Comment: @GabrielBlanco I don't know what you have in semester courses but look at the comments i put below your answer.. its a guess of what you can try

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.*, sc.* FROM semestercourses AS sc
NATURAL LEFT JOIN course AS c 
NATURAL LEFT JOIN courserequirements AS cr
NATURAL LEFT JOIN studentcoursecomplete AS scc  
WHERE 
sc.CourseID NOT IN (SELECT CourseID FROM studentcoursecomplete)
    AND 
(cr.RequirementID IS NULL OR cr.RequirementID IN (SELECT CourseID FROM studentcoursecomplete))
```

Comment: hmm you could try putting studentid=1 right before you do anything else in the WHERE... so like `WHERE sc.StudentID = 1 AND sc.CourseID NOT IN(`

Comment: I just did sc.StudentID, I don't know if you have that in the semestercourses table.. but if you don't then use scc.StudentID

Comment: yes i have a semestercourses table and there CourseID coloumn in table .. so what i can do ?

Comment: can you post a sqlfiddle with how I had it in my answer? it would make this much easier... but try adding to your WHERE clause `scc.StudentID = 1`

Comment: im going to need you to post a sqlfiddle then so I can test it. can't do much from where I am

Comment: it's too long letter !! how can i post it

Comment: post the url of the sqlfiddle in a comment like the one i have looks like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7c9a/1

Comment: here the database with my code .. it's work correctly but i need it for specific student .. like SID=1
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2242d/2/0

Comment: ok thanks I just edited my answer with a working copy of your query. try it and let me know if thats exactly what you want with more than one user